# Selected option value doesn't keep and display

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site using existing forest theme. I customize the search function by adding the location of country and province, but it seems like when I choose a value option, the selected value doesn't keep and display there. Even though it worked when I added on another page. 
The website that I am working on is http://www.asiamodeldirect.com/, and the problem that I am talking about is also right on the homepage where you see the part country and province selection
Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Can anybody please help me on this problem?